# Error Message: No such element exception?

Tags: java, error-handling, java.util.scanner

I am unsure why I am getting the following message?:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at assessed_practical_2.PossibleQuestionSolution.main(PossibleQuestionSolution.java:24)
```

Here is my code for the main method:

```
    package assessed_practical_2;

    //Importing Resources (Random)
    import java.util.Random;
    //Importing Resources (Scanner)
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PossibleQuestionSolution {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // Setting up Scanner for User Input
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            // var declaration
            int userChoice;

        do{ 
            // Invoke displaymenu
            displayMenu();

            // Get user Input for the menu
            System.out.println("Please enter choice from menu...");
            userChoice = scanner.nextInt();

            // Switch statement to decide which method to invoke dependent upon user input

            switch (userChoice) {

            case 1:
                sayUserName();
                break;
            case 2:
                sayUserNameLoop();
                break;
            case 3:
                generateRandomNumbers();
                break;
            case 4:
                triangleArea();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Quitting Program");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry didnt recognise Input");
            }// Switch Statement end

        }while (userChoice!=5);

        System.out.println("Goodbye...");

            scanner.close();
        }// end of main method
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help, I assume it is a problem with the nextint line in reference to the scanner but I am unable to fix it!

Comment: you should be checking that nextInt or nextLine exist, so you should have something like:

while scanner.hasNextInt(){
}
or
while scanner.hasNextLine(){
}

Comment: You are not showing exact line where you might have this error, i am afraid

Comment: This code compiles and runs for me with no errors. We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the following and it seems to be allowing my program to run:

public class PossibleQuestionSolution {

```
// Setting up Scanner for User Input
public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // var declaration
    int userChoice;

do{ 
    // Invoke displaymenu
    displayMenu();

    // Get user Input for the menu
    System.out.println("Please enter choice from menu...");
    userChoice = scanner.nextInt();

    // Switch statement to decide which method to invoke dependent upon user input

    switch (userChoice) {

    case 1:
        sayUserName();
        break;
    case 2:
        sayUserNameLoop();
        break;
    case 3:
        generateRandomNumbers();
        break;
    case 4:
        triangleArea();
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Quitting Program");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Sorry didnt recognise Input");
    }// Switch Statement end

}while (userChoice!=5);

System.out.println("Goodbye...");


}// end of main method
```

Basically what i did was change the scanner to a public resource that all methods could use, this seems to have sorted out the problem and No longer get the error exception.